# Calling async function in if else

Tags: javascript, dictionary, asynchronous, leaflet

everybody.
I am currently creating an application that allows to plant markers in the leaflet map and according to the lat and Ing it looks for the address at the given coordinates. For address finding I am using "Nominatim" which works very well. Unfortunately, there is an asynchronization in my code that I am not able to solve.

This is my class constructor

```
class Ereigniss {
    constructor(latlng, { info = null, time = null, isMarker = null, geoLabel = null } = {}) {
        this.latlng = latlng
        this.info = info
        this.time = time
        this.geoLabel = geoLabel
        this.isMarker = isMarker
        if (!isMarker) {
            this.startMarker = latlng[0]
            this.endMarker = latlng[latlng.length - 1]
        }
        this.id = Date.now()
    }


    setGeoLabel(geoLabel) {
        this.geoLabel = geoLabel
        return this
    }

    setInfo(info) {
        this.info = info
        return this
    }

    setTime(time) {
        this.time = time
        return this
    }

    setLatlng(latlng) {
        this.latlng = latlng
        return this
    }
}
```

This is ajax function, which looks for address on given lat and lng. This work very well I would say.

```
function getGeoLabel(lat, lng) {
            $.ajax({
                url: `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=geocodejson&lat=${lat}&lon=${lng}`,
                method: 'get',
                success: resp => {
                    let label = resp.features[0].properties.geocoding.label
                    let trimString = label.split(',').slice(0, 4)
                    let labelResult = trimString.join(',');
                    return labelResult
                },
                error: resp => {
                    console.log(resp + 'err');
                }
            })
        }
```

And finally, a function that does everything necessary. If I insert a marker into the card, the first thing created is the new Class constructor "Ereigniss". This will give me the necessary information for **lat and lng**, which now the function **getGeoLabel** has to work with, and I will use the return of this function in the third step to call **setGeoLabel** from the constructor, which will give my object the information about the address. Unfortunately the response is always **undefined**. I know that the problem will be in asynchronization but I have absolutely no idea how to solve this problem effectively. Thank you for your help

```
    map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
                let type = e.layerType,
                    layer = e.layer,
                    latlng = layer._latlngs || layer._latlng;
                // console.log(latlng.lat, latlng.lng);
    
                if (type === 'marker') {
                    let markerObj = new Ereigniss(latlng, { isMarker: true })
                    let foundLabel = getGeoLabel(latlng.lat, latlng.lng)
                    markerObj.setGeoLabel(foundLabel)
                    markerIcon = new L.marker([latlng.lat, latlng.lng], {
                        draggable: false
                    }).addTo(map)
          console.log(markerObj) //undefined
               }
       })
```

Comment: use async/await and the issue goes away ... add a return here ...`function getGeoLabel(lat, lng) {
return $.ajax({` ... an async here `map.on('draw:created', async function (e) {` and an await here `let foundLabel = await getGeoLabel(latlng.lat, latlng.lng)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your solution doesn't work completely. Instead of undefined, the result is now [object Object] which does not contain the address of the point on the map but some unnecessary information about the leaflet map - "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright"

Comment: sure, but that's because I forgot jquery's ajax promises are ... difficult ... so, the resolved value you are getting is `resp` ... not `labelResult` ... you could, instead of a `success` property on the $.ajax call use `.then`  i.e. `return $ajax(url ... method ... nothing else).then(resp => your success code including return labelResult)`